# How should I describe the "relationship" between me and postdoc in our lab if I am getting recomendation letter from her?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

How should I describe the relationship between me and postdoc in our lab if I am getting recommendation letter for phD admission?
Advisor? Superviser? reasearch advisor?...
She has a title of research professor.

Comment: Is she actually your supervisor?

Comment: What is your position in the lab?  Undergraduate research assistant?  Graduate research assistant?  How do you interact?  Does she give you assignments and review your work? Do you collaborate? Work on totally different things? Is there another professor who is formally your thesis advisor? What I'm getting at is: if you want us to help you find the right word to describe the relationship, you'll have to describe the relationship to us.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this person is not formally your manager nor supervisor, the correct term would be **colleague**.

Comment: Or perhaps "colleague and mentor", if you want to emphasise the fact that the other person is in a position to judge your work.

Comment: Alternatively: "She is a postdoc in our lab."

Answer (score 1):

Why not just ask her/your lab's PI if you're not sure? They are in the best position to answer the question.

Advisor is sometimes a reserved word for people listed on a thesis, so if I had to guess I would say that this is not the right word.

Also - to be honest it probably doesn't matter very much, you're focusing on an unimportant detail in my opinion. What matters is that her reference is positive and supports your application in the strongest terms. Having sat in graduate admissions committees myself, I cannot imagine a scenario where we look at an application and say "it's good, **but** they didn't list the referee's title appropriately, gotta reject it now!"